# Checking if a selectbox is empty

Tags: javascript

How do you check if a selectbox is empty with plain JavaScript and alert the user "The selectbox contains 0 items."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById('select').options.length == 0) 
    alert('The selectbox contains 0 items');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gf8QK/

Comment: Or simply `document.getElementById("select").length === 0`. An [`HTMLSelectElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) is one of the few array-like elements: it has a `length` property which represents a [length](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-lengthofarraylike) and numeric indices for each `<option>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (selectObject.options.length == 0) {
    alert('The selectbox contains 0 items');
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp